# error: object of type 'llvm::SourceMgr::SrcBuffer' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I faced this error when I was compiling with `clang`. It will be appreciate if any body can help.

Working on 32 bit windows 7 platform and using Codelite to compile
the error happend in section below:

```
typename iterator_traits<_BI1>::difference_type __n;
      for (__n = __last - __first; __n > 0; --__n)
        *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
      return __result;
    }
```

and it is the error message:

```
c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++\bits/stl_algobase.h:546:18:
error: object of type 'llvm::SourceMgr::SrcBuffer' cannot be assigned
because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
    *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours googling i find a way to double cross  the code:
i must put:

```
*--__result = *--__last;
```

instead of

```
 *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
```

then it works!
[stl_algobase.h source from MIT](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/libstdc++/include/bits/stl_algobase.h)
have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling a newish version of clang I'd be surprised your setup compiles it at all. It looks like it's using gcc4.6.1 which I don't think supports enough c++11 to compile LLVM and clang which require almost full compliance.

If it works though, awesome.

Comment: I got that error again! what am i supposed to do? the error message is: c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++\bits/stl_algobase.h:547:18: error: object of type 'llvm::SourceMgr::SrcBuffer' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted